# Concurrency with pthreads, a typical misbehaviour

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I'm not sure whats wrong with the program below, but it doesn't print each and every language once, but randomly some more often, some more less and some wont print

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>



char *messages[] = { 
    "English: Hello World!", 
    "French: Bonjour, le monde!",
    "Spanish: Hola al mundo", 
    "Klingon: Nuq neH!",
    "German: Guten Tag, Welt!", 
    "Russian: Zdravstvytye, mir!",
    "Japan: Sekai e konnichiwa!", 
    "Latin: Orbis, te saluto!"
};
#define NUM_MESSAGES (sizeof( messages ) / sizeof( char* ))


void *PrintHello( void *messageid )
{
    pthread_t taskid;
    int *id_ptr, message_num;

    taskid = pthread_self();
    printf( "This is thread with ID %lu.\n", taskid );

    message_num = *((int *) messageid);
    printf( "%s \n", messages[message_num] );

    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_MESSAGES];
    int rc, i;


    for( i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++ ) {
        void * argument = (void*) &i;
        rc = pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, argument );
        if( rc ) {
            printf( "ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc );
            exit( -1 );
        }
    }




    for( i = 0; i < NUM_MESSAGES; i++ ) {
        pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
    }

    pthread_exit( NULL );
}
```

I guess the problem is somehow connected with the argument pointer. I tried to lock different parts but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the address of the variable `i`, which **the main thread keeps changing**. So you're at the mercy of scheduling: will anyone change `i` before your thread has a chance to run ?

Instead, you could try directly passing the string, greatly simplifying the code:

```
rc = pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, messages[i]);

void *PrintHello(void *arg)
{
    char *msg = arg;
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    return NULL;
}
```

---

There's another, poorer alternative where you pass the actual value of `i` as the argument (not its address).

Comment: Thank you for your help. That worked for me. Is there any attempt to solve this thing with locks? I tried locking before setting "argument" and unlock after the thread creation but that didn't work :/ I know that would be the idea of concurency but just for my intrest :)

Comment: @smoes No, locking isn't feasible here. You would have to somehow lock before creating the thread and unlock in the thread once you pass the point where you stop using `i`.

Comment: @smoes, not using pthread mutexes - pthread mutexes must be released by the same thread that locks them, but here you're waiting for the other thread to capture the value before unlocking. Moreover, you're losing much of the benefit of threading by only letting one thread run at once. The usual solution is to allocate a new buffer for each thread that you fill in any arguments in, then pass to pthread_create. The new thread then takes care of freeing the buffer. No locks needed this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical `race` condition. 
To be exact, after a new thread is created, the executing order of the threads determines the program outcome. There are two situations:

1. When the thread function `PrintHello` is executed before the next increments `i++` and the assignment `void * argument = (void*) &i;` in `main` thread, it outputs what you expect.
2. When the new thread `PrintHello` has been created but does not get scheduled until the next `i++` executed in `main` thread. In this situation, your reference of `argument` in the thread function, namely `message_num = *((int *) messageid);` is not what you expect.

A solution for this is to dynamically allocate (using `malloc`)`argument`, and `free` them in the thread function after using it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass scalar integer arguments to thread functions is to (ab-)use the following text from §6.3.2.3 of the C99 standard:

> (5) An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Except for the last part of the second sentence, the following code should work on most systems:

```
int int_val;
...
pthread_create(..., ..., thread_func, (void *)int_val);
```

and then in `thread_func` cast it back to integer:

```
void *thread_func (void *data)
{
    int int_arg = (int)data;
    ...
}
```